# PHP While loop displaying only last row

Tags: php, mysql, while-loop, tcpdf

I'm using **TCPDF** library to generate PDF of a table .

Table has few number of rows say 10

Among that two rows has same invoice number **"78650"**

Now i am **selecting by invoice number** and as desired it should generate PDF with **two rows**.

But instead it is only fetching the **second row** that is the last row. That is Serial no 2 is only taken .

***Code Below :***

```
<?php
require_once('TCPDF/tcpdf.php');
$pdf = new TCPDF(PDF_PAGE_ORIENTATION, PDF_UNIT, PDF_PAGE_FORMAT, true, 'UTF-8', false);
$pdf->SetDefaultMonospacedFont(PDF_FONT_MONOSPACED);
$pdf->SetAutoPageBreak(TRUE, PDF_MARGIN_BOTTOM);

if (@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php')) {
require_once(dirname(__FILE__).'/lang/eng.php');
$pdf->setLanguageArray($l);
}
$pdf->SetFont('helvetica', '', 9);
$pdf->AddPage();

$html1 = '<table  cellspacing="0" class="table table-striped">
<tr>

<th>SL No.</th>

<th>Product</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Qty</th>
<th>Total</th>
</tr>';

$sql = ("select * from invoice WHERE invoice_no = 78650 ORDER BY invoice_id ASC");
$result=mysqli_query($connection,$sql);
$i = 1;
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
$pr = $row['product'];  
$dr = $row['description'];  
$qty = $row['qty']; 
$total = $row['total']; 

$html2 =  "<tr>

<td>".$i."</td>                         
<td>".$pr."</td>
<td>".$dr."</td>
<td>".$qty."</td>
<td>".$total."</td>
</tr>";

$i++; } 

$sql_1 = ("select *,SUM(total)as tot from invoice WHERE invoice_no = 78650 GROUP BY invoice_no");
$result_1=mysqli_query($connection,$sql_1);
$row_1 = mysqli_fetch_array($result_1);
$tot = $row_1['tot']; 
$html3 =    "<tr>
<td></td>

<td></td>
<td></td>
<td>Total: </td>
<td>".$tot."</td>
</tr>                       
</table>";
$html = $html1.$html2.$html3;
$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, 0, true, 0);
$pdf->lastPage();
$pdf->Output('htmlout.pdf', 'I');
?>
```

Comment: You need to concatenate the `$html2` variable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's because for iteration you're replacing the content of `$html2`. You will need to append the content instead.

So take the blank `$html2` variable outside the loop and append the result as you iterate the loop.

Code would look something like this,

```
$html2="";
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
$pr = $row['product'];  
$dr = $row['description'];  
$qty = $row['qty']; 
$total = $row['total']; 

$html2 = $html2."<tr>
<td>".$i."</td>                         
<td>".$pr."</td>
<td>".$dr."</td>
<td>".$qty."</td>
<td>".$total."</td>
</tr>";

$i++; 

}
```

Comment: Awesome. Please accept it as correct answer if it solved your issue.

Comment: Done mate ! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The second fetch overwrites the variable $html2. You can use an array $html2[$i].

Answer (score 0):

```
$tbl_header = '<table border="1"><tr>
        <th>FirstName</th><th>LastName</th><th>Gender</th><th>E-Mail</th><th>Mobile</th><th>DateOfBirth</th><th>Country</th><th>State</th><th>City</th><th>Address</th><th>Zipcode</th><th>File</th></tr>';
$tbl_footer = '</table>';

$tbl = '';
 while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
   {  
$tbl .= '
<tr><td>'.$row['firstname'].'</td><td>'.$row["lastname"].'</td><td>'.$row["sex"].'</td><td>'.$row["email"].'</td><td>'.$row["mobile"].'</td><td>'.$row["dob"].'</td><td>'.$row["country"].'</td><td>'.$row["state"].'</td><td>'.$row["city"].'</td><td>'.$row["address"].'</td>  
<td>'.$row["zipcode"].'</td>
<td><img src="'.$row["file"].'"/></td>
</tr>
';

}
//$pdf->writeHTML($html, true, false, true, false, '');
$pdf->writeHTML($tbl_header . $tbl . $tbl_footer, true, false, false, false, '');
```